# Can array_filter filter an array by more than one value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

The code below filters a multidimensional array by the ID of 152.

```
$new = array_filter($test, function ($output) {
    return ($output['_id'] == 152);
});
```

Is there a way to make it work with multiple IDs? For example 152, 154, 155

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can try this :

```
$new = array_filter($test, function ($output) {
    return (in_array($output['_id'] , [152,154,155]));
});
```